# java applet not working in iframe IE all versions

Tags: java, reactjs, iframe, applet

I have portal which opens a react application in an iframe.
One one page I am dynamically adding applet code like this :

```
win.document.getElementById('rdsInfo').innerHTML = '<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550" archive="http://xbx.net:7950/rmsPortal/resources/sapplauncher.jar" code="com.bci.rms.pca.applet.AppLauncherApplet.class">'+
                        '<param name="SEC_TOKEN" value="'+token+'" />'+
                        '<param name="WSDL" value="http://rmsd.xbx.com/dpwserice/DPPcAnywhereAuditService.jws?WSDL" />'+
                        '<param name="PCASCRIPTNAME" value="rdsclient.vbs" />'+
                        '<param name="SCRIPTDOWNLOADPATH" value="http://qalxweb.global.bc.net/RMSFiles/QA2/pcascript/" />'+
                        '<param name="mayscript" value="true" />'+
                        '<param name="JS_METHOD_NAME" value="rdsAppletStatus" />'+
                        '<param name="DP_HOST_URL" value="http://lxbeat1.global.bc.net:7950/rmsDPPtal" />'+
                    '</object>'
```

This applet loads properly when i access react application not from the portal.
But  when application is opened by portal in an iframe ,It does append the applet code but does not run it.

Note: portal and react application is in different origins.Should i write it in some different way to get it run or is it not possible ??

Comment: Hint: java applets ... that is **dead-end** technology. If possible, simply forget about using them. Chrome has long disabled java; and java9 will also  drop 'em out.

Comment: Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: That very much depends on the actual problem at hand. In 2016, there are zillions of very powerful Javascript frameworks around to create powerful and feature-rich "applications" that run on the client side in the browser. So, you probably should sit down with the folks that tell you to use an applet ... why an applet? What is the thing supposed to do? But the thing is: such discussions go way beyond a "reasonably scoped" question on SO. In other words: A) clarify your requirements B) talk to some experience people ... then decide the best solution to your problem.